# Data Modeling to find the best Y

Tags: modeling, dataset

From a list of cities, I want to know which is the best to move in. I've data like rent prices per square feet, job offers, medium wages and medium cost of living, including groceries, leisure and another features. In this scenario, I have the X's (features) but what´s the Y? I can choose some feature, but I don't know how to choose the best. Please brothers, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: You, and you alone, have to determine what "best" means: we cannot decide that for you.

Comment: Thank you @whuber for your response. I will try to answer what "best" means. Let's say that the best city, is that have the best rated restaurants (by michelin stars), high job quantity offers in some field and at the end of the month, the medium wage covers all the bills. How can I solve this? Thanks again.

Comment: There is no "solution": *you* have to establish the formula whereby you will combine quantitative measurements of these features.  It cannot be inferred from the data alone.  See our posts related to rating, ranking, and valuation at [tag:rating].